# Eliminating $t$ in the solution of a Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My task is to show that the trajectories of the system:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=y$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=x$

are hyperbolas given by $H(x,y)=y^2-x^2=c.$

Solving the above system I got:

$x=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}$, $y=c_1e^t-c_2e^{-t}$.

My question is, how can I eliminate $t$ from the solutions $x$ and $y$ to get $H(x,y)?$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=e^t$.  Then

$$x = c_1 u + \frac{c_2}{u} \implies c_1 u^2 - x u + c_2 = 0$$

or

$$u = \frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2-4 c_1 c_2}}{2 c_1} $$

$$y = c_1 u - \frac{c_2}{u} \implies y = \frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2-4 c_1 c_2}}{2} - \frac{x \mp \sqrt{x^2-4 c_1 c_2}}{2} = \pm \sqrt{x^2-4 c_1 c_2}$$

The result follows.

Comment: thanks Sir Ron' my next question will be is this the general method for eliminating $t$?

Comment: You could do it here or in the diff eq'n as shown in other answers.  Up to you.

Comment: Now, I know ... thank you so much Sir Ron.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Chain rule:
given $\frac{dx}{dt}=y$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=x$, by the chain rule

$x=\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} \Longrightarrow x=\frac{dy}{dx}y$.

Rearraging we have the differential equation (without reference to t)
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y}.$

Solving this with separation of variables gives you your hyperbolas:
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y} \longrightarrow y \;dy = x\;dx \Longrightarrow \frac{y^2}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$.

Simplifying we get $y^2-x^2 = C$.

Comment: thanks for your answer but, I want to figure out how eliminating $t$ will lead to $H(x,y)$.

Comment: Solving the differential equation I have given leads directly to $H(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks WSL. Its an easier method indeed.

Comment: I have added in this final calculation. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

From your solutions, $x+y=2c_1e^t$ while $x-y=2c_2e^{-t}$.
Multiplicating them will give you the formula for your hyperbolas, with $c=-4c_1c_2$.

Comment: NIce answer Davide, my next question will be, is this the general method in eliminating $t$?

Comment: I'd say the general method depends from the equation (so it's not really that general I presume). Where would you use that method?

Comment: So that if ever I encountered simillar problems above, I can now easily eliminate $t$.

Comment: Well if you have two equations, like in this case, in which you have the sum and the subtraction of two terms like $a+b$ and $a-b$, adding and subtracting the two is useful (and easy) because they cancel out one another, and you get $2a$ in the first and $2b$ in the second one. This is often called _decoupling_.

Comment: This requires an extra step in which you can cancel out the $t$'s, because of the exponential. It was wasy to see that multiplicating them gets rid of the variable.

Comment: You're welcome. Just so you know, the constant $c$ is not $4c_1c_2$ but $-4c_1c_2$. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Divide first equation by second eliminating dt:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x}{y}.$

Integrate to get equilateral hyperbolas.